# Difference between folder/ and folder

Tags: directory, azure-active-directory, filepath

When changing directories and traversing filepaths, I noticed that sometimes users apply `cd foo/bar/` and sometimes `cd foo/bar`.

I was wondering what the difference was, if any? I presume there's no difference in the context of simply changing directories, but are there consequences of using each method elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, there is no difference when changing directories on the command line. You're also right in presuming there is no difference between:

`file/path/example/` and `file/path/example` in other contexts too (where `example` represents a folder).